# Reverse Proxy on Ubiquiti EdgeRouter POE

Tags: debian, proxy, router

Is it possible to build a lightweight reverse proxy server on an Edgerouter?
I think that it should be possible, as the OS on the router is Debian. But after looking through the questions/answers I didn't find any previously records of this topic.
Do anyone know of this - and how to?

I found out that there is 3.8G 'disk' inside the router, and there is debian-utils among other debian stuff. There are no official repository listed.
The purpose of converting the router into reverse proxy is to handle incomming SSL requests. At the moment we have a redirection on the webserver IP to mail or fileserver IP's. Our concern is if the Webserver should fail, then webmail and webfile access on SSL won't work.
So thougts have been to insert the router between the USG gateway and the servers - and make the router/proxy do the correct IP assignments.

Comment: Is it actually running Debian, or just something that is based on Debian.  If you ssh to it, does it have a /etc/apt/sources.list pointing that the official debian repositories?  The small size of the firmware download (https://www.ubnt.com/download/edgemax/edgerouter-poe/default/edgerouter-erlite-3erpoe-5-firmware-v190) ~80MB makes me think this is not a a full-blown Debian system.

Comment: No repositories found.

Answer (score 1):

The Edge Router comes bundled with Lighttpd. So long as you're not doing anything too complicated you can rewrite the configuration file(s).

Know, however, that the router is designed to default itself to a particular state, and - unless understood - will overwrite your changes. mgbowen's Github repository<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/mgbowen/letsencrypt-edgemax)</sup> to integrate Let's Encrypt certification is a good starting point.

While it is possible to install other services, such as Nginx, so long as they have a compatible `mips` package and the `sources.list` is updated to reflect this. Of course, the whole configuration would have to be rebuilt from scratch if you want to use something other than Lighttpd.

And before I get too far away from this topic, I want to also add (and stress) that installing applications with reckless disregard can turn your router into a brick. You'd have to get a management cable and install the firmware again; not a trivial task and not for the faint of heart!

With those cautions out-of-the-way, I'll share some snippets of what I've done.

Lighttpd.conf.patch

```
  --- include "conf-enabled/10-ssl.conf"
  +++ # include "conf-enabled/10-ssl.conf"    # original
  +++ include "conf-enabled/11-ssl.conf"      # updated
  +++ include "conf-enabled/20-network.conf"  # redirects
```

11-ssl.conf

```
  $SERVER["socket"] == "192.168.1.1:80" {
      ### Handle the existing 80 to 443 traffic
      .
      .
      .

      ### Added for personal use:
      $HTTP["host"] == "foo.internal.tld" {
        proxy.server = ( "" =>
          (
            ( "host" => "192.168.1.1", "port" => <random unused port> )
          )
        )
      }
  }
```

20-network.conf

```
     $SERVER["socket"] == "192.168.1.1:<port defined in 11-ssl.conf>" {
       url.rewrite-once = ( "^(?!/gui)(.*)" => "/gui$1" )
       proxy.server = ( "" =>
         ( "" =>
           ( "host" => "<IP of server running service>", "port" => <port for service> )
         )
       )
     }
```

NOTE:

The reason for the port-to-port-to-port redirection is because of the version of Lighttpd, currently, available and the suggested workaround<sup>[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19466700/982245)</sup> for port-forwarding.

REFERENCE:

1. https://github.com/mgbowen/letsencrypt-edgemax
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19466700/982245